# How can I connect xampp database to a remote server?

Tags: database, xampp, localhost, connect, remote-server

Does anybody know a reliable way to connect xampp mysql database on a localhost to a remote server, so that a website would be working?

Comment: Be more specific and add what you have already done

Answer (score 0):

one way is to use ngrok.io this service will expose your local server to the world or maybe a get a static IP address from you ISP... but you should always always use a hosting service be it a cloud service like GCP or AWS or just namecheap or bluehost.